# Definition of a point $x$ in a Riemann sum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x_k) \Delta(x)$$

I am interested in what $x_k$ is. On stackexchange I have seen $x_k$ being defined as:

$$x_k = \Delta(x)(k) + a$$

Where $a$ is the initial beginning etc...

Is there are a proof of this, or is it a definition?

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly, $x_k$ denotes a point in the $k$th part of the partition of $[a,b]$. It doesn't actually matter which point: the limit is supposed to exist regardless of what point is chosen within the $k$th part of the partition.

Equivalently, $x_k$ denotes the left endpoint of one of the $k$th part of the partition, where the limit is over partitions whose widths go to $0$.

Often in first calculus classes, one evaluates integrals by assuming that the left endpoints of the partitions of the interval $[a,b]$ into $k$ same-sized parts is sufficient (and it is sufficient for continuous functions, for instance). In this case, the left endpoint is $a$. The next endpoint would be $a + \frac{b-a}{k}$, and so on. Is this a necessary definition? No. But it's more concrete, and sometimes having something concrete is nice in a first calculus class.

You might also be interested in a [post I wrote for my students](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1259) about calculus and the intuition behind some of these ideas. There's also a gif of integration by rectangles, which I rather like.

Answer (score 0):

More generally a Riemann sum can use any partition of the interval $[a,b]$; i.e., a division of $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals not necessarily of the same size.

If the Riemann integral exists, it is equal to your limit on the RHS using a partition of subintervals of the same size, where $$ \Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} \ \ \hbox{ and } \ \ x_k = a + k\Delta x$$

Comment: How do you derive $x_k = a + k\Delta(x)$?

Comment: In other words, the partition used for the Riemann sum is defined to be $[a,x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]$, (where $x_n = b$).